# Check if the home page is checked out by the current user

Tags: 2010, publishing, client-object-model

Using JSOM, I would like to check if the home page is checked out, and if the current user is the one who checked-out the page.

The test occurs from another page.

Here is what I have now:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = context.get_site().get_rootWeb();
var me = rootWeb.get_currentUser();
var homePageUrl = (_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl === '/' ? '' : _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl) + '/pages/Accueil.aspx'; // my home page

var homePage = rootWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(homePageUrl);

var checkoutUser = homePage.get_checkedOutByUser();

context.load(me);
context.load(checkoutUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var message = null;
        // some tests 
        if (checkoutUser && checkoutUser.get_id() !== me.get_id()) {
            message = "HP is not checked-out or checked out by someone else";
        }

        if (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        // TODO: add error handler
    })
    );
```

If the homepage is checked out this is working as expected. However, if the home page is not checked out, the query fails and I get this error:

> "Impossible d’appeler la méthode ou de récupérer la propriété d’un objet null. L’objet renvoyé par la pile des appels suivante est null. « CheckedOutByUser\r\nGetFileByServerRelativeUrl\r\n »"

which can be translated as:

> "Impossible to call method or retrieve property of a null object. Object return by the following stacktrace is null: CheckedOutByUser\r\nGetFileByServerRelativeUrl\r\n

What's wrong? How to fix?

PS: it's a SP2010 publishing site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs due to [SP.File.checkedOutByUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556740%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object properties are not being initialized when the File is not checked out.

### Solution

Instead of retrieving `SP.File.checkedOutByUser` object at line:

```
context.load(checkoutUser);
```

replace it with retrieving `SP.File` object:

```
context.load(homePage);
```

Then you could determine File `SP.File.checkedOutByUser` and `SP.File.get_checkOutType` properties as demonstrated below.

The fixed example:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = context.get_site().get_rootWeb();
var me = rootWeb.get_currentUser();
var homePageUrl = (_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl === '/' ? '' : _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl) + '/pages/Accueil.aspx'; // my home page


var homePage = rootWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(homePageUrl);
context.load(me);
context.load(homePage);

context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {

        var checkOutType = homePage.get_checkOutType();
        if(checkOutType === SP.CheckOutType.online){  /* Is file checked-out ? */
             var checkoutUser = homePage.get_checkedOutByUser(); 
             if (checkoutUser && checkoutUser.get_id() !== me.get_id()) {

             }
        }



    },
    function () {
        // TODO: add error handler
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually the way to fix my code, but I used another method that relies on the REST services. Basically, I can query my data in a single ajax call:

```
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl === '/' ? '' : _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
    debugger;
    var getHPStatus = $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages()?$select=ExtraitVersId&$filter=Nom%20eq%20%27Accueil.aspx%27",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    getHPStatus.then(function(data){
        var checkedOutUserId = data.d.results[0].ExtraitVersId;
    });
```

Basic, but working.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the `checkOutType` property and if the value is not `none`, then find who has checkedout the file.

```
var value = SP.File.get_checkOutType();
```

Comment: Does it means that I'll have to chain multiple queries?

Comment: Yes, I also think so.